# Saving a file backup at certain points in the day

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble getting vba to autosave a file backup at certain points in the day.

When I run "Backup" by itself it works fine. I can't get the trigger to run "Backup" to work and stepping into the code isn't really assisting with troubleshooting.

```
Sub SaveBackup()

    Dim Trigger As Date
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:25:00"), "Backup", , True
      
End Sub
```

```
Sub Backup()
  
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:25:00"), "Backup", , True
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="Z:\Global\Quality\Expired FG and 31's\" & "FG Expiration Test" & " " & Format(Now(), "MM.DD.YYYY") & ".xlsm"
    'FileFormat:= 52 means save as XLSM

End Sub`
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong about this, but wouldn't the workbook have to be open for the event to be triggered? Instead, I've always converted my script into a .vbs file and then run it on a timer using Windows Task Scheduler.

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/how-to-automatically-run-excel-vba-macros-daily